# Primefaces p:fileDownload with datatable

Tags: java, primefaces

I got a datatable that return all files of a folder, and that file can be downloaded using the primefaces p:filedownload resource.

It is working fine, but when the code is loaded i cant modify the file because the FileInputStream is oppened.
And if i close the FileInputStream during the datatable load, p:filedownload doesnt work

Anyone?

(If i uncomment the commented part, the filedownload doesnt work, and if i keep it, i cant edit the file trough the windows)

Java:

```
public List<StreamedContent> getAnexosQuestionarios() {
List<StreamedContent> resultado = new ArrayList<StreamedContent>();
File[] arquivos = FileHelper.listarArquivos(selected.getEmpresa().getDiretorio(), FileHelper.QUESTIONARIOS);

if (arquivos != null) {
    for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(arquivo.getAbsolutePath());
        String extensao = arquivo.getName().substring(arquivo.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,
        MimeTypes.valueOf(extensao).getMimeType(),
        arquivo.getName());
        resultado.add(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    // try {
    // stream.close();
    // } catch (IOException e) {
    // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }
}
return resultado;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p:panel header="Questionários">
                    <p:dataTable id="dtAnexosQuestionarios"
                        value="#{tecnologiaEmpresaController.anexosQuestionarios}"
                        var="arquivo" widgetVar="dtAnexosQuestionarios"
                        emptyMessage="Nenhum anexo disponível"
                        style="width:50%; border:2 !important; border-color:white !important;">
                        <p:column headerText="" style="width:20px;">
                            <h:graphicImage
                                value="../resources/images/#{tecnologiaEmpresaController.getExtensao(arquivo.name)}.png" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Arquivo">
                            <p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="#{arquivo.name}"
                                ajax="false">
                                <p:fileDownload value="#{arquivo}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
```

Thank you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was solved, thanks to sabrina.bettini

here's my code fixed:

Code to fill the datatable:

```
    public List<StreamedContent> getAnexosInformacoes() {
List<StreamedContent> resultado = new ArrayList<StreamedContent>();
File[] arquivos = FileHelper.listarArquivos(selected.getEmpresa().getDiretorio(), FileHelper.INFORMACOES);

if (arquivos != null) {
    for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(arquivo.getAbsolutePath());
        String extensao = arquivo.getName().substring(arquivo.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,MimeTypes.valueOf(extensao).getMimeType(),arquivo.getName());
        resultado.add(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

return resultado;
}
```

Code to open the file, using actionlistener:

```
StreamedContent arquivo;

public void prepararArquivoInformacoes(final StreamedContent arq) {
InputStream stream = null;
String caminho = FileHelper.retornarCaminhoPasta(selected.getEmpresa().getDiretorio(), FileHelper.INFORMACOES);
try {
    stream = new FileInputStream(caminho + File.separator + arq.getName());
    this.arquivo = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, MimeTypes.valueOf("pdf").getMimeType(), arq.getName());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public StreamedContent getArquivo() {
return arquivo;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <p:panel header="Informações">
                <p:dataTable id="dtAnexosInformacoes"
                    value="#{tecnologiaEmpresaController.anexosInformacoes}"
                    var="arquivo" widgetVar="dtAnexosInformacoes"
                    emptyMessage="Nenhum anexo disponível"
                    style="width:50%; border:2 !important; border-color:white !important;">
                    <p:column headerText="" style="width:20px;">
                        <h:graphicImage
                            value="../resources/images/#{tecnologiaEmpresaController.getExtensao(arquivo.name)}.png" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Arquivo">
                        <p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="#{arquivo.name}" 
                            ajax="false" actionListener="#{tecnologiaEmpresaController.prepararArquivoInformacoes(arquivo)}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{tecnologiaEmpresaController.arquivo}" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
        </p:panel>
```

FileHelper:

```
static FileService fileService;

public static final String PASTA_RAIZ = "P:\\";
public static final String INFORMACOES = "1. Informacoes";
public static final String QUESTIONARIOS = "2. Questionarios";
public static final String RELATORIOS = "3_Relatorio";

public static File[] listarArquivos(final String empresa, final String tipo) {
File file = new File(PASTA_RAIZ + empresa + File.separator + tipo + File.separator);
return file.listFiles();
}

public static String retornarCaminhoPasta(final String empresa, final String tipo) {
File file = new File(PASTA_RAIZ + empresa + File.separator + tipo + File.separator);
return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using 
StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,"application/octet-stream",                                            arquivo.getName());

---

This is how I do it in my application:

I do not use datatable. I use ui:repeat the iterates through a list of ArquivoAnexo.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{lista}" var="arquivo" varStatus="status">

<h:commandLink actionListener="#{cadastrarBean.prepararDownloadArquivo(arquivo)}" styleClass="downloadArquivoAnexo">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{cadastrarBean.arquivoParaDownload}"/>
</h:commandLink>


public void prepararDownloadArquivo(ArquivoAnexo arquivo) {
    byte[] conteudo = arquivo.getArquivo();
    String nome = arquivo.getNomeArquivo();
    this.arquivoParaDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(conteudo), "application/octet-stream", nome);
}

public StreamedContent getArquivoParaDownload() {
    return arquivoParaDownload;
}

public interface ArquivoAnexo {    
    byte[] getArquivo();    
    String getNomeArquivo();
    String getDescricao();    
    void setDescricao(String descricao);
    void setArquivo(byte[] conteudo);    
    void setNomeArquivo(String nome);
}
```

Comment: Hello Sabrina! I got the same error: "Read error". The problem is right in the "new FileInputStream"...if i close it, i can't open the file, but if i keep it, i can't modify the file

Comment: I do the same in my application, but I have never tried to edit the downloaded file. Do you want to modify the file that is in the server? Or you just want to download it, and then modify it locally?

Comment: i would like to change the file in the server, so the user will always have the most updated file

Comment: I think you will have to do the download of the file and then upload it back to the server.

Comment: Hello Sabrina, using your example i just found out how to make it work! It seems that the StreamedContent wasnt working as it should, but now its ok! Thank you so much!

Comment: And is it really changind the file in the server?