# How to download files in the filtered datatable of Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable which allows you to download files. It works. However when I try to download a file after filtering returned is first on the list.

This image shows that when clicked on teste4.txt the same file was downloaded. This is correct. [image: Correct download]

This other picture shows that when clicked on file teste4.txt, after filtering, the downloaded file was teste1.txt [image: Download wrong]

This is my file containing the datatable:

```
<h:form id="hFormListaArquivosRegiao2" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:dataTable id="pDataTableListaArquivos" var="arquivo" value="#{arquivoBean.listaArquivos}" filteredValue="#{arquivoBean.filteredListaArquivos}">

        <p:column id="pColumnNomeArquivo" headerText="#{msg.NomeDoArquivo}" sortBy="#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}">

            <h:commandLink action="#{arquivoBean.download}" title="#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}">

                <h:outputText value="#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{arquivoBean.arquivo}" value="#{arquivo}" />

            </h:commandLink>

        </p:column>

</h:form>
```

This is the method of backingBean responsible for downloading:

```
public void download() throws Exception {

    logger.debug("NOME ARQUIVO: "+ ContextoBean.CAMINHO_ARQUIVOS + arquivo.getNomeArquivo() +", "+ arquivo.getNomeArquivo());

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    pushArquivo(facesContext.getExternalContext(), ContextoBean.CAMINHO_ARQUIVOS + arquivo.getNomeArquivo(), arquivo.getNomeArquivo());
    facesContext.responseComplete();

}
```

This is the helper method of backingBean responsible for downloading:

```
private void pushArquivo(ExternalContext externalContext, String nomeArquivo, String nomeDeExibicao) throws IOException {

    // Info sobre a lógica usada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686821/execute-backing-bean-action-on-load
    File descritoArquivo = new File(nomeArquivo);
    int length = 0;
    OutputStream os = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
    String extencaoArquivo = externalContext.getMimeType(nomeArquivo);
    externalContext.setResponseContentType((extencaoArquivo != null) ? extencaoArquivo : "application/octet-stream");
    externalContext.setResponseContentLength((int) descritoArquivo.length());
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nomeDeExibicao + "\"");

    // Stream to the requester.
    byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(descritoArquivo));
    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
        os.write(bbuf, 0, length);
    }

    in.close();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Primefaces' [download component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf)? It should be compatible with their own filters

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I implemented something like this: [Primefaces p:fileDownload with datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144306/primefaces-pfiledownload-with-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would make a few changes to get the current arquivo by method parameter :

```
<h:commandLink action="#{arquivoBean.download(arquivo)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

In the bean :

```
public void download(Arquivo arquivo) throws Exception {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    pushArquivo(facesContext.getExternalContext(),
        ContextoBean.CAMINHO_ARQUIVOS + arquivo.getNomeArquivo(),
        arquivo.getNomeArquivo());
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: This solution has generated an exception: WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) #{arquivoBean.download(arquivo)}: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{arquivoBean.download(arquivo)}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What is you JSF implementation?

Comment: My implementation is Mojarra 2.0

Comment: I'm almost getting. Now I can get the correct object. The problem now is that the download window does not open. My commandLink was so: <h:commandLink title="#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}">
       
       <a onclick="downloadArquivo([{name:'codigoArquivo', value:'#{arquivo.codigoArquivo}'}, {name:'criterioListaArquivosParam', value:'/regioes/r2/'}]);" href="javascript:void(0)">#{arquivo.nomeArquivo}</a>

Comment: and the download method looked like this:  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String codigoArquivo = (String) map.get("codigoArquivo");
        String criterioListaArquivosParam = (String) map.get("criterioListaArquivosParam");
        
  
  ArquivoRN arquivoRN = new ArquivoRN();
  
  Arquivo arquivo = arquivoRN.busArquivo(codigoArquivo);

Comment: and this: FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  pushArquivo(facesContext.getExternalContext(), ContextoBean.CAMINHO_ARQUIVOS + criterioListaArquivosParam + arquivo.getNomeArquivo(), arquivo);
  facesContext.responseComplete();

Comment: the push method I just changed the signature: String nomeDeExibicao to Arquivo arquivo

Comment: and modified: externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nomeDeExibicao.getNomeArquivo() + "\""); to externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + arquivo.getNomeArquivo() + "\"");